# Compare multiple columns and update data if matched

Tags: excel

Using Excel 2013 and need to figure out how to compare and update values. If anyone is able to help, I would greatly appreciate it!

In column A, I have a new list of 6000+ user names. 
 In column B, I have the new phone number associated with each user account. 
 In column D, I have an old list of 6000+ user names.
 In column E, I have the old phone number associated with each user account.

I need help in figuring out how to compare the data in column A and Column D. If they match, I then need to have the value in Column E updated to match the value in Column B.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(D1,$A:$A, 0), INDEX($A:$B, MATCH(D1,$A:$A, 0), 2), E1), "")
```

and put it in F1, then drag it down. See if that works for you. Once it's done, just copy and paste special values into E.

Answer (score 0):

Do a VLOOKUP.

You will get plenty of resources on net

Here is one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wH6jPVHnc9Q

Answer (score 0):

Add columns to show which list the data came from and copy the old list below the new. Select your data and apply Remove Duplicates to the user name column, if you want a single up-to-date list.